# Controller is not working when I put it in another project OData .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, controller, odata

I have two projects: OData (ASP.Net Core API) and Console(.Net core). I added the ASP.Net Core project to Console as a reference and starting service from Console. I create a controller class in the Console project but it is not working. Here is my project structure:

[image]

I am starting OData service in SimpleServer:

```
namespace SimpleServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var url = "https://localhost:44383";
            var actionBuilder = Configuration.GetBuilder();
            StartHost(url, actionBuilder);
        }

        internal static IHost StartHost(string url, Action<IApplicationBuilder> action)
        {
            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseHttpSys(op => op.UrlPrefixes.Add(url));
                webBuilder.Configure(action);
            }).Build();
            host.Start();
            return host;
        }
    }
}
```

The OData service is working. It is showing EntitySets:
[image: OData]

But it is showing 404 error when I go to `https://localhost:44383/odata/Student`
It is working when I move StudentController class to the OData project. I want to put controller class in another app (my console app), how can I do it? Here is controller classes:

```
public class StudentController : BaseController<Student>
{

}



public class BaseController<TEntity> : ODataController where TEntity : class
{
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery()]
    public IActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<TEntity> queryOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var list = new List<Student>
        {
            CreateNewStudent("Cody Allen", 130),
            CreateNewStudent("Todd Ostermeier", 160),
            CreateNewStudent("Viral Pandya", 140)
        };
        return Ok(list);
    }

    private static Student CreateNewStudent(string name, int score)
    {
        return new Student
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = name,
            Score = score
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Multiple Startup Projects ?

Comment: @Shivendra I don't understand what are you mean. I made oData project as a class library and starting from several vays

Comment: Your OData project is clearly not a class library from looking at the project icon.
That means AspNetCore applicationhost.

Comment: What is the purpose of this even?

Comment: @DIlshodK I believe the Sample server is created as class library & oData project is created as Web project. However, it does not matter, if you wish to run the sample server project, you should right click it and set it as startup project.

Comment: @Shivendra Sample project is a console application. As you can see It has main function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below fix this problem:
I made a controller project as a class library and add following code:

```
    var modelAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Users\Owner\source\repos\ODataCoreTest\ClassLibrary2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ClassLibrary2.dll");
        services.AddControllers(mvcOptions =>
             mvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false).PartManager.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(modelAssembly));
```

Now it is working correct

Comment: How did you get the references to work I'm getting an error in my class lib that reads ... Assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData, Version=8.0.10.0' uses 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.5.0'